# Insert row issue windows authentication

Tags: wpf, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I have created my Database : ETSI and a Table : References (dbo.References in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio).

Here is my App.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLServerConnection" connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=ETSI;Trusted_Connection=True;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;"/>
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Here is my method that catches this exception source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider

```
static void AddReference(string specification_number, string specification_version)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServerConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO References(specification_number,specification_version) VALUES(@specification_number, @specification_version)", con);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@specification_number", specification_number);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@specification_version", specification_version);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

                    Console.Write("spec number ) "+specification_number+" spec verison ) "+specification_version);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception source: {0}", e.Source);
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see I use windows authentication with my database but I can't insert a row in it..

Comment: Do you get an exception? If so, please post the message rather than have us guess...

Comment: And what exactly *is* your exception?

Comment: It seems to be my SQLCommand statement syntax because when I catch System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlException I have : "Incorrect syntax near the keyword References"

Comment: My Table is composed of more than this 2 elements, do I have to specify all in my statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"References" is a system Table.. So insert is impossibe.